# does an object lose its constness when an implicit conversion occurs?

Tags: c++, object, constants, implicit-conversion

I have done a little experiment and I don't understand the output !

```
class C {
public:
  operator int() const { std::cout << "I'm const" << std::endl;}
  operator int(){ std::cout << "I'm not const" << std::endl;}
};

void f(int){};

int main()
{
  f(C());
}
```

Why does this output `"i'm not const"` ? Shouldn't the first cast of the C object, which is an rvalue and therefore const, be prioritary?

Thanks ! :)

Edit : If it can make the question more precise :

In constrast :

```
void g(C const &){ std::cout << "I take a const" << std::endl; };
void g(C &){ std::cout << "I take a non const" << std::endl; };
```

> g(C()) outputs "I take a const".

Comment: Why do you say "lose"? Why did you expect anyone to be const in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A temporary isn't constant:

```
C();  // not const
```

If you want to refer to it constantly, cast it:

```
f(static_cast<const C&>(C()));
```

The point is that the object whose member function (here the conversion operator) is called is not constant. This has nothing to do with the *result* of the conversion.

The result isn't actually required to be constant, either. Suppose we add another class:

```
class D { };

class C {
  // ...
  operator D() { return D(); }
};

int main()
{
  D d;
  static_cast<D>(C()) = d;      // OK: assign d to the result of the conversion
  // static_cast<int>(C()) = 6; // Error: left-hand side is not an lvalue
}
```

Comment: Okay. So nothing is defaulted to const, but then why does g behave differently than C::operator int() ?

Comment: No, nothing to do with constness, but only with lvalue/rvalue-ness. You cannot assign to an rvalue, which is the result of conversion-to-int. I'm editing to add this example.

Comment: Okay. But why when calling g( C() ) , g(C const & ) is used whereas  when calling int(  C() ) , int(C &) is used?

Comment: @Ragnar: It's on of the great mysteries of rvalueness. I do not know why, but you may call whatever non-const methods you like on an rvalue, but it may not be passed into a user-defined function as a non-const reference. I find this perplexing and bizarre in the extreme myself, and I have never seen it explained satisfactorily.

Comment: @Ragnar: The temporary only *binds* to `C const &`, but it is not itself constant. This is merely a language design decision (which is very clever), but you can freely cast away the constness and modify the object if you must, as the temporary object itself is not immutable. Note also that the temporary will happily bind to the *mutable* `C&&`.

Comment: @Omnifarious You shall not question the law.

Comment: @Ragnar There is no `int(C &)`. There is just `C().operator int()`. There is no reference binding at all here.

Comment: @KerrekSB C/C++ are the result of series of very short-sighted decision that end-up in a mess that no ISO committee seems to fully understand, much less be able to sort out.

Answer (score 1):

It may surprise you, but this is perfectly legal C++:

```
class C { } ;
int main()
  {
  C d ;
  C() = d ;
  }
```

See [this ideone link](http://ideone.com/PXz7D) for proof. So `C()` is an lvalue.

Comment: "_is an lvalue_" Wrong. It is a rvalue. Maybe you believe that lvalue means "can be at the left of ="? It does not. Lvalue means lvalue. It "means" nothing. It's a set of (mostly arbitrary) rules.

Comment: `C()` is an "Explicit type conversion (functional notation)" **[expr.type.conv]** (it converts nothing to something). "_The expression `T()`_ (...) _creates a prvalue of the specified type_" "_Temporaries of class type are created_ (...) _a conversion that creates a prvalue_" **[class.temporary]**

Comment: In the historical classification, it was just a **rvalue**. Anyway, the expression refers to an class object, that has an address, can have member functions called...

Comment: "_Lvalue means lvalue._" This means that there isn't a cute definition for lvalue, rvalue... the exact definition involves a long list of cases, and the description has a long list of specific properties. If you want a **short** definition for lvalue: "you can apply the address-of operator to it" It's short, cute, and also **wrong** for both primitive and user defined types.

Comment: "_I don't think C() qualifies as either of_ **simple-type-specifier** typename-specifier" Seriously??? And you think [expr.type.conv] applies to what exactly?

Comment: "_the parentheses debar C() from both categories_" Yes, of course! "_Is it a simple-type-specifier, or a typename-specifier?_" Neither, obviously. Do you even think `int(1)` is a valid C++ expression?

Comment: Prove me (or yourself) that `int(1)` is a valid C++ expression.

Comment: I've deleted all my comments, because it was a waste of time asking you for sensible information. I still don't understand any of your your cryptic asides. I suggest you delete yours too, and then we can all forget the whole thing.

Comment: Do you still claim that: "So C() is an lvalue."?

Comment: "_I still don't understand any of your your cryptic asides._" Here something not so cryptic: you seem unable to read the standard, or even a grammar; a lot worse, you do not consider your own conclusions with a critical mind. It's one thing to make a wrong deduction, it's another thing to conclude something clearly ridiculous and stick to it because you believe your proof is valid. I **tried** to tell that in a nice way. You are also unable to get a hint.